# Show block content inside custom node template

Tags: 7, theming

I've created a custom template (`node--<mytype>.tpl.php`), and I'd like to display the calendars from the [Availability Calendars](http://drupal.org/project/availability_calendars) module. I don't understand how to load them.

I've tried with this code, but it doesn't work.

```
$block = module_invoke('availability_calendar', 'block_view');
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to make your block available inside your `node.tpl.php`, so edit `template.php` and add the following:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $YOURBLOCK = block_load('MODULENAME', 'BLOCKDELTA');
  $variables['YOURBLOCK'] = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
}
```

Then, on your node.tpl.php you can `print $YOURBLOCK;` anywhere you want.

And yes, you have to call two "private" functions from block module, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke/7#comment-15884

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `print $block['content'];`

Make sure that you're using appropriate arguments for `module_invoke` [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7)

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 30);

@arg 1 : module name
@arg 2 : hook name like block_view, block_info
@arg 3 : id or delta of the block e.g 30, map-block_1
```

in D7 you can also try `block_load` [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_load/7)